# Android Application allowing BLE Secure Connection pairing authentication using Wrong Passkey

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, maui, ble-pairing

I'm working on an application requirement to create a BLE secure connection between an Android app and a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) enabled device.

In the process of accessing the Pairing/Bonding API, the application get requested with a Pairing Popup (managed by the Android Framework), where user need to entered Passkey information.

Assume the Passkey is 123456, and if the user enters anything other than this, the pairing fails and works perfectly as expected. However, if the user enters 123456XXXX (any additional character appended to correct Passkey), it will still authenticate the user and give access to device data.

I tested it on nRF Connector - Android, and it behaves the same way like the above; while the iOS app does not allow this, it still failed the authentication.

Environment - Android 13 | Samsung S-23 Device.

Any suggestion or input !

Comment: Seems like a bug. Have you reported it to Android's bug tracker? In any case, it does not really affect the security.

Comment: Thanks Emil. This has created here, do let me know if you have any input. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/315187773